# Substitute for create-react-app "homepage" setting in a non create-react-app application

Tags: reactjs, routes, create-react-app, react-router-dom

In a create-react-app application, setting my homepage in package.json gives me what I expect.  I set it to:
homepage: '/someUrl' and in my app, if my URL is localhost:3000/someUrl/another, and I refresh, it goes there without issue.

In my non create-react-app application (it's still a react project, just started from scratch), if I navigate to localhost:3000/someUrl/another by normal means I get the page, but then if I hit refresh I get a white page with:
`Cannot GET /someUrl/another`

Has anyone come across this?  I'm trying to figure out what setting "homepage" in create-react-app does exactly so that I can duplicate this in my non CRA react app.

Thank you for any help,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to use History HTML5 to config homepage & use publicPath configuration of webpack to config path of assets.
Example:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory({
  basename: YOUR_HOME_PAGE,
  hashType: "slash"
});
```

and inside webpack configuration: (in case of config path assets to prevent 404 on production)

```
output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath("js/[name].[chunkhash].js"),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath("js/[id].[chunkhash].js"),
    publicPath: YOUR_HOME_PAGE
}
```

Hope this help for you!

Comment: I understand the part about the webpack configuration, but how would I use:


import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory({
  basename: YOUR_HOME_PAGE,
  hashType: "slash"
});

Comment: In case of your router not using hash #, remove line hash type, only use basename: YOUR_BASE_NAME. So your URL app always will be url/YOUR_BASE_NAME/:path-router.